# retrieving documentation from utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

Is there a way to retrieve the documentation, displayed in html [here](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.9/doc/stdio/Stdio/In_channel/index.html)
directly from utop.

I can get the *type* by using

```
utop # open Core;;
─( 10:41:50 )─< command 4 >─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop # #typeof "In_channel.input_char";;
val Core.In_channel.input_char : Core.In_channel.t -> Base.char Base.option
─( 10:41:54 )─< command 5 >─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
```

or

```
utop # #show In_channel.input_char;;
val input_char : in_channel -> char option
─( 10:43:00 )─< command 7 >────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────{ counter: 0 }─
utop #
```

but the doc is richer

```
  val input_char : t ‑> Stdio__.Import.char Stdio__.Import.option

Read one character from the given input channel. 
Return None if there are no more characters to read.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the doc directly from utop, you can install this package from opam: https://github.com/reynir/ocp-index-top

Then a `#doc` directive will be available and show you what you want.

An alternative is to use ocp-browser. That can display all the types and the documentation.

Comment: excellent ! do you know why that does not compile with 4.07.0 ? I don't see this constraint anywhere in https://github.com/reynir/ocp-index-top yet I get a message to that effect "$ opam install ocp-index-top                                                                  [ruby-2.3.7p456]
The following dependencies couldn't be met:
  - ocp-index-top → ocp-index → ocaml < 4.07 → ocaml-base-compiler < 4.07.0
      conflict with the base packages of this switch"

Comment: From what I gathered, a release of ocp-index is required to get compatibility with 4.07. Hope it will happen soon.